# error when depoloy flutter project with CodeMagic

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

i have an flutter project and it is run good on emulator and my android device, but when i upload it to Github and make (commit) show me this error to review:
[image]

i cannot do anything about this error, and it is not affect my project when run it?
 and when i ignore it and deploy to GitHub and try to build and deploy project with CodeMagic, i faced this error in (Running Test) step :

```
   == Testing ==

== flutter test --machine ==
{"protocolVersion":"0.1.1","runnerVersion":null,"pid":2836,"type":"start","time":0}
{"suite":{"id":0,"platform":"vm","path":"/Users/greenhouse/clone/test/widget_test.dart"},"type":"suite","time":1}
{"test":{"id":1,"name":"loading /Users/greenhouse/clone/test/widget_test.dart","suiteID":0,"groupIDs":[],"metadata":{"skip":false,"skipReason":null},"line":null,"column":null,"url":null},"type":"testStart","time":2}
{"count":1,"type":"allSuites","time":10}
{"group":{"id":2,"suiteID":0,"parentID":null,"name":null,"metadata":{"skip":false,"skipReason":null},"testCount":1,"line":null,"column":null,"url":null},"type":"group","time":9907}
{"test":{"id":3,"name":"Counter increments smoke test","suiteID":0,"groupIDs":[2],"metadata":{"skip":false,"skipReason":null},"line":76,"column":3,"url":"package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart","root_line":14,"root_column":3,"root_url":"file:///Users/greenhouse/clone/test/widget_test.dart"},"type":"testStart","time":9909}
{"testID":1,"result":"success","skipped":false,"hidden":true,"type":"testDone","time":9916}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════","type":"print","time":10433}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"The following assertion was thrown building MisSplash(state: _OneState#0408f(ticker active)):\nMediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.\nNo MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of().\nThis can happen because you do not have a WidgetsApp or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce\na MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets.\nThe context used was:\n  Scaffold(dirty, state: ScaffoldState#1ae2e(lifecycle state: initialized, tickers: tracking 1\n  ticker))","type":"print","time":10438}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"\nWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack:","type":"print","time":10439}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#0      MediaQuery.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart:528:5)","type":"print","time":10450}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#1      ScaffoldState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1529:50)","type":"print","time":10451}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#2      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3862:12)","type":"print","time":10451}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#3      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)","type":"print","time":10452}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#4      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)","type":"print","time":10453}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#5      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)","type":"print","time":10453}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#6      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)","type":"print","time":10453}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)","type":"print","time":10453}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#8      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)","type":"print","time":10454}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#9      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)","type":"print","time":10454}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#10     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)","type":"print","time":10455}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#11     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)","type":"print","time":10455}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)","type":"print","time":10456}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#13     RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:933:16)","type":"print","time":10456}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#14     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:911:5)","type":"print","time":10457}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#15     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:925:7)","type":"print","time":10458}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)","type":"print","time":10458}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#17     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2273:33)","type":"print","time":10459}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#18     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:805:18)","type":"print","time":10460}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#19     _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:268:5)","type":"print","time":10461}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#20     _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:988:15)","type":"print","time":10462}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#21     _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:928:9)","type":"print","time":10462}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#22     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:719:9)","type":"print","time":10463}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#25     TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:69:41)","type":"print","time":10465}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#26     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:706:27)","type":"print","time":10465}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#27     WidgetTester.pumpWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:250:22)","type":"print","time":10465}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#30     TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:69:41)","type":"print","time":10466}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#31     WidgetTester.pumpWidget (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:247:27)","type":"print","time":10466}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#32     main.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/greenhouse/clone/test/widget_test.dart:16:18)","type":"print","time":10467}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"<asynchronous suspension>","type":"print","time":10467}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#33     testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:82:23)","type":"print","time":10468}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#34     TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:571:19)","type":"print","time":10469}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"<asynchronous suspension>","type":"print","time":10469}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#37     TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:555:14)","type":"print","time":10470}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#38     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:898:24)","type":"print","time":10472}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#44     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:895:15)","type":"print","time":10473}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#45     testWidgets.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:81:22)","type":"print","time":10473}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#46     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:168:27)","type":"print","time":10474}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"<asynchronous suspension>","type":"print","time":10474}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#47     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:250:15)","type":"print","time":10475}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"<asynchronous suspension>","type":"print","time":10479}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#52     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:247:5)","type":"print","time":10479}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#53     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:166:33)","type":"print","time":10479}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#58     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:165:13)","type":"print","time":10480}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"<asynchronous suspension>","type":"print","time":10480}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#59     Invoker._onRun.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:400:25)","type":"print","time":10482}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"<asynchronous suspension>","type":"print","time":10482}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#73     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)","type":"print","time":10483}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#74     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)","type":"print","time":10483}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#75     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)","type":"print","time":10484}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"(elided 32 frames from class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, and package stack_trace)","type":"print","time":10485}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════","type":"print","time":10485}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════","type":"print","time":10486}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:\n  Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree\n  Actual: ?:<zero widgets with text \"0\" (ignoring offstage widgets)>\n   Which: means none were found but one was expected","type":"print","time":10487}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"\nWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack:","type":"print","time":10489}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#4      main.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/greenhouse/clone/test/widget_test.dart:19:5)","type":"print","time":10490}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"<asynchronous suspension>","type":"print","time":10493}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#5      testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:82:23)","type":"print","time":10493}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#6      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:571:19)","type":"print","time":10493}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"<asynchronous suspension>","type":"print","time":10498}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#9      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:555:14)","type":"print","time":10498}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#10     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:898:24)","type":"print","time":10498}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#16     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:895:15)","type":"print","time":10498}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#17     testWidgets.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:81:22)","type":"print","time":10498}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#18     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:168:27)","type":"print","time":10499}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"<asynchronous suspension>","type":"print","time":10499}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#19     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:250:15)","type":"print","time":10499}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"<asynchronous suspension>","type":"print","time":10499}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#24     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:247:5)","type":"print","time":10499}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#25     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:166:33)","type":"print","time":10500}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#30     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:165:13)","type":"print","time":10500}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"<asynchronous suspension>","type":"print","time":10500}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#31     Invoker._onRun.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:400:25)","type":"print","time":10501}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"<asynchronous suspension>","type":"print","time":10501}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#45     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)","type":"print","time":10501}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#46     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)","type":"print","time":10501}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"#47     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)","type":"print","time":10502}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"(elided 28 frames from class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, and package stack_trace)","type":"print","time":10502}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"\nThis was caught by the test expectation on the following line:\n  file:///Users/greenhouse/clone/test/widget_test.dart line 19\n\nThe test description was:\nCounter increments smoke test","type":"print","time":10504}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════","type":"print","time":10505}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════","type":"print","time":10505}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"The following message was thrown:\nMultiple exceptions (2) were detected during the running of the current test, and at least one was\nunexpected.","type":"print","time":10506}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════","type":"print","time":10507}
{"testID":3,"error":"Test failed. See exception logs above.\nThe test description was: Counter increments smoke test","stackTrace":"","isFailure":false,"type":"error","time":10518}
{"testID":3,"result":"error","skipped":false,"hidden":false,"type":"testDone","time":10521}
{"success":false,"type":"done","time":10560}


Tests failed :|
Flutter test run failed

== Tests failed, skip build ==
```

there is no error when i run the project? how can find the bugs?, and i try to read this log above, but i cannot understand the error?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing this problem -.-

Comment: yes, just delete the test folder from project or make it empty

Answer (score 0):

Just Disable the test phase, this might work.
Go to the workflow settings then to Test 
then uncheck both option for Run "Flutter test" and Stop the "Build if test Fails"
Save it and try again.
Hope it'll solve but you cannot test your app that's the drawback.